# Function parameter failing to execute in Node.JS Jasmine test

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I'm trying to execute a function that is passed in as a parameter in my Jasmine test.

I'm calling my function within this for-loop, but getting `"TypeError: barbican_function is not a function"`

```
/************************************************************************
Stress Test Code to Test High Request Hits To API Endpoint
**************************************************************************/
//Stress Test for Key Retrieval
var stressTestRunner = function(barbican_function) {
  describe("Stress test", function() {
    it("Send X requests to single key", function(done) {
        for (var x = 0; x < requestsToHit; x++) {
          barbican_function();
        }
        done();
    })
  })
};

stressTestRunner(stressTest_retrieve_secret());




function stressTest_retrieve_secret() {

   //My code here
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of this line:

```
stressTestRunner(stressTest_retrieve_secret());
```

You are *calling* the function and passing in the function's return value.

What you most likely mean is:

```
stressTestRunner(stressTest_retrieve_secret);
```

which passes in a function reference.

Debugging hint:  Next time you get an error like this, open up your browser's debugging tools and put a breakpoint on your code. That would let you examine the various variable and parameters to see what is going on.